# Session storage in express-ws using express-session

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session, ws

I am writing a server side script that has websocket routes using express-ws such as:

*/init* -  which is called when the website loads on the onload function. In the /init route I am setting up some session variable

*/request* - this is called when any request is made to the server like on a button click. I will do some backend processing here

The problem is although the session ids are same when calling both the routes. The session variables I initialized in */init* route are not to be found with the request made to the */request* route.

Below is the server side code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');

const sessVariables = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('session-variables.json').toString());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'crack',
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 3600000 }
}))

app.get('/init',(req, res)=>{
    req.session.sessId = 0; //storing the variable here
    console.log('websocket server is up');
    res.status(200).send();
})

app.ws('/request',(client, req)=>{
    console.log(client);
    client.on('message',(data)=>{
        console.log(req.session)
        console.log(data, req.session.id, req.session.sessId); //sessId blank undefined
    })
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{console.log('Server started at port 3000')});
```

Client Side Script

```js
window.onload = function(){  //calling the init route to store the session
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/init',
        success: function(){
            console.log('session initialized');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }
    })
}

function sendText(){ //calling the function on a button click
    console.log(document.getElementById('txtsendtext').value);
    postData();
}

var Channel = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/request/');

Channel.onopen = function(event){
    console.log(event);
}

function postData(){
    Channel.send('data');
}
```

***UPDATE:*** Session id is different on init call and the websocket call after that but after the websocket call the session id persists and on page refresh the init is called again and the sessId is stored and I can access it in the websocket call as well.I am getting the session variables on page reload and it persists after then.

**Why am I getting different session ids for /init and /request?**

---

**SOLVED:** Needed to set the ajax call async to false to wait for the ajax call to set the session id.

Comment: Can you share your code please !

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Added the code